# LaTeX Error: File `biblatex-apa.sty' not found

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

This is my first document with LaTeX and I have this problem: Every time I try to compile I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `biblatex-apa.sty' not found.
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I guess it is due to LaTeX not finding the package `biblatex-apa`. Is this right?
If it is right, I don't know why LaTex can't find it, because I have installed it.

I saw you like to have MWEs for helping so I hope this is what you need:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt,
    %twocolumn,
    headings=normal     % big,small
]{scrreprt} %scrartcl,scrbook,scrreprt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{mathptmx}               
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage[style=apa, 
        hyperref=true,        
        isbn=false,
        firstinits=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-apa}
\bibliography{Data_richtig}    
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

blabla...

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). I edited for you and marked the code. Further, I removed thanks and name below the post, it's not usual here, and your name is automatically below your post at the right.

Comment: From the manual, it seems that you don't have to load the package, just specify the style. So if you remove `\usepackage{biblatex-apa}`, does it work?

Answer (score 12):

You should not load `biblatex-apa` as a package. To use the `apa` style, just specify it in the options for [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa), as you've done already. Hence, remove `\usepackage{biblatex-apa}`, and it should work.

From the manual, section 3:

> Specify the style in the usual way when loading BibLaTeX. If you are
>   using `babel`:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[american]{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
> ```
>
> or `polyglossia`:
>
> ```
> \usepackage{polyglossia}
> \setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
> ```

---

### For versions of `biblatex-apa` older than 7.5 (2017-11-05)

With versions this old you need an additional `\DeclareLanguageMapping`:

From the manual, section 2:

> Specify the style in the usual way when loading biblatex.
>
> ```
> \usepackage[american]{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
> \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
> ```

About localisation:

> Normal use will invoke babel with the ‘american’ babel language. After
>   loading babel and biblatex, put this in the preamble (see full
>   preamble example in section 2 above):
>
> ```
> \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Here is an example to load the German localisation strings. This
>   assumes that you are using the `babel` package with the appropriate
>   language option:
>
> ```
> \DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yex, it does work now. The trick was, that I removed the hyperref=true,        
            isbn=false,
            firstinits=true

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it does work now. The trick was, that I removed the hyperref=true, isbn=false, firstinits=true, I also removed the \usepackage{biblatex-apa} and I added the last line you suggested (\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}.

Comment: @Anna: You may also thank Torbjørn T. by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).

Comment: In more recent versions of `biblatex-apa` the `\DeclareLanguageMapping`s need not be executed manually, `biblatex-apa` will perform the automatically in the background.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I edited my answer to reflect that.